# How to create a plot with dynamic variables

Tags: python, matplotlib, variables, dynamic

Using matplotlib library on Pyhton, I would like to plot some graphs with dynamic y variables, i.e. variables which would change according to another variable stated before my plot functions.

From my imported data frame, I have extracted different gases concentration (M**_conc) and fluxes (M**_fluxes).

```
M33_conc = ec_top["M  33(ppbv)"]
M39_conc = ec_top["M  39(ncps)"]
M45_conc = ec_top["M  45(ppbv)"]
M59_conc = ec_top["M  59(ppbv)"]
M69_conc = ec_top["M  69(ppbv)"]
M71_conc = ec_top["M  71(ppbv)"]
M81_conc = ec_top["M  81(ppbv)"]
M137_conc = ec_top["M 137(ppbv)"]
M87_conc = ec_top["M  87(ppbv)"]
M47_conc = ec_top["M  47(ppbv)"]
M61_conc = ec_top["M  61(ppbv)"]

M33_flux = ec_top["Flux_M  33"]
M45_flux = ec_top["Flux_M  45"]
M59_flux = ec_top["Flux_M  59"]
M69_flux = ec_top["Flux_M  69"]
M71_flux = ec_top["Flux_M  71"]
M81_flux = ec_top["Flux_M  81"]
M137_flux = ec_top["Flux_M 137"]
M87_flux = ec_top["Flux_M  87"]
M47_flux = ec_top["Flux_M  47"]
M61_flux = ec_top["Flux_M  61"]
```

I want to be able to plot the evolution of these gases concentration/fluxes with time, with only one function which would allow me to choose between plotting the concentration or the fluxes of these gases.

Here is what I have written so far :

```
color_1 = 'black'
graph_type='conc'

fig, ((ax1, ax2, ax3), (ax5, ax7, ax8),(ax9,ax10,ax11)) = plt.subplots(3, 3, sharex=True, sharey=False)
fig.suptitle('Influence of wind direction of BVOCs concentration')
ax1.plot(wind_dir,'M33_'+graph_type,linestyle='',marker='.',color=color_1)
ax1.set_title('Methanol')
ax1.set(ylabel='Concentration [ppbv]')
ax2.plot(wind_dir,M39_conc,linestyle='',marker='.',color=color_1)
ax2.set_title('Water cluster')
ax2.set(ylabel='Concentration [ncps]')
ax3.plot(wind_dir,M45_conc,linestyle='',marker='.',color=color_1)
ax3.set_title('Acetaldehyde')
ax3.set(ylabel='Concentration [ppbv]')
# ax4.plot(wind_dir,M47_conc,linestyle='',marker='.',color='color_1')
# ax4.set_title('Unknown')
ax5.plot(wind_dir,M59_conc,linestyle='',marker='.',color=color_1)
ax5.set_title('Acetone')
ax5.set(ylabel='Concentration [ppbv]')
# ax6.plot(wind_dir,M61_conc,linestyle='',marker='.',color='color_1')
# ax6.set_title('Unknown')
ax7.plot(wind_dir,M69_conc,linestyle='',marker='.',color=color_1)
ax7.set_title('Isoprene')
ax7.set(ylabel='Concentration [ppbv]')
ax8.plot(wind_dir,M71_conc,linestyle='',marker='.',color=color_1)
ax8.set_title('Methyl vinyl, ketone and methacrolein')
ax8.set(ylabel='Concentration [ppbv]')
ax9.plot(wind_dir,M81_conc,linestyle='',marker='.',color=color_1)
ax9.set_title('Fragment of monoterpenes')
ax9.set(ylabel='Concentration [ppbv]',xlabel='Wind direction [°]')
ax10.plot(wind_dir,M87_conc,linestyle='',marker='.',color=color_1)
ax10.set_title('Methylbutenols')
ax10.set(ylabel='Concentration [ppbv]',xlabel='Wind direction [°]')
ax11.plot(wind_dir,M137_conc,linestyle='',marker='.',color=color_1)
ax11.set_title('Monoterpenes')
ax11.set(ylabel='Concentration [ppbv]',xlabel='Wind direction [°]')
plt.show()
```

When I try to parametrize the data I want to plot, I write, for example :

```
'M33_'+graph_type
```

which I am expecting to take the value 'M33_conc'.

Could someone help me to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! I have shared an answer presenting one possible approach among others, let me know in case you are actually looking for something very different.

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned wanting to plot the evolution of the gases with time, but in the code sample you have given, you use `wind_dir` as the x variable. In this answer, I disregard this and use time as the x variable instead.

Looking at your code, I understand that you are wanting to create two different figures made of small multiples, one for gas concentrations and one for gas fluxes. For this kind of plot, I recommend using pandas or seaborn so that you can plot all the variables contained in a pandas dataframe at once. Here I share an example using pandas.

Because you are wanting to plot different measurements of the same substances, I recommend creating a table that lists the names of the variables and units associated with each unique substance (see `df_subs` below). I create one using code to extract the units and share it here, but this is easier to do with spreadsheet software.

Having a table like that makes it easier to create a plotting function that selects the group of variables you want to plot from the `ec_top` dataframe. You can then use the pandas plotting function like this: [`df.plot(subplots=True)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/visualization.html#subplots).

Most of the code shown below is to create some sample data based on your code to make it possible for you to recreate exactly what I show here and for anyone else who would like to give this a try. So if you want to use this solution, you can skip most of it, all you would need to do is create the substances table your way and then adjust the plotting function to fit your preferences.

#### Create sample dataset

```
import io                          # from Python v 3.8.5
import numpy as np                 # v 1.19.2
import pandas as pd                # v 1.1.3
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    # v 3.3.2
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

pd.set_option("display.max_columns", 6)

rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=1) # random number generator

# Copy paste variable names from sample given in question
var_strings = '''
"M  33(ppbv)"
"M  39(ncps)"
"M  45(ppbv)"
"M  59(ppbv)"
"M  69(ppbv)"
"M  71(ppbv)"
"M  81(ppbv)"
"M 137(ppbv)"
"M  87(ppbv)"
"M  47(ppbv)"
"M  61(ppbv)"

"Flux_M  33"
"Flux_M  45"
"Flux_M  59"
"Flux_M  69"
"Flux_M  71"
"Flux_M  81"
"Flux_M 137"
"Flux_M  87"
"Flux_M  47"
"Flux_M  61"
'''
variables = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(var_strings), header=None, names=['var'])['var']

# Create datetime variable
nperiods = 60
time = pd.date_range('2021-01-15 12:00', periods=nperiods, freq='min')

# Create range of numbers to compute sine waves for fake data
x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, nperiods)

# Create dataframe containing gas concentrations
var_conc = np.array([var for var in variables if '(' in var])
conc_sine_wave = np.reshape(np.sin(x), (len(x), 1))
loc = rng.exponential(scale=10, size=var_conc.size)
scale = loc/10
var_conc_noise = rng.normal(loc, scale, size=(x.size, var_conc.size))
data_conc = conc_sine_wave + var_conc_noise + 2
df_conc = pd.DataFrame(data_conc, index=time, columns=var_conc)

# Create dataframe containing gas fluxes
var_flux = np.array([var for var in variables if 'Flux' in var])
flux_sine_wave = np.reshape(np.sin(x)**2, (len(x), 1))
loc = rng.exponential(scale=10, size=var_flux.size)
scale = loc/10
var_flux_noise = rng.normal(loc, scale, size=(x.size, var_flux.size))
data_flux = flux_sine_wave + var_flux_noise + 1
df_flux = pd.DataFrame(data_flux, index=time, columns=var_flux)

# Merge concentrations and fluxes into single dataframe
ec_top = pd.merge(left=df_conc, right=df_flux, how='outer',
                  left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

```
ec_top.head()

#                       M 33(ppbv)  M 39(ncps)  M 45(ppbv)  ... Flux_M 87   Flux_M 47   Flux_M 61
# 2021-01-15 12:00:00   11.940054   5.034281    53.162767   ... 8.079255    2.402073    31.383911
# 2021-01-15 12:01:00   13.916828   4.354558    45.706391   ... 10.229084   2.494649    26.816754
# 2021-01-15 12:02:00   13.635604   5.500438    53.202743   ... 12.772899   2.441369    33.219213
# 2021-01-15 12:03:00   13.146823   5.409585    53.346907   ... 11.373669   2.817323    33.409331
# 2021-01-15 12:04:00   14.124752   5.491555    49.455010   ... 11.827497   2.939942    28.639749
```

#### Create substances table containing variable names and units

The substances are shown in the figure subplots in the order that they are listed here. Information from this table is used to create the labels and titles of the subplots.

```
# Copy paste substance codes and names from sample given in question
subs_strings = """
M33    "Methanol"
M39    "Water cluster"
M45    "Acetaldehyde"
M47    "Unknown"
M59    "Acetone"
M61    "Unknown"
M69    "Isoprene"
M71    "Methyl vinyl, ketone and methacrolein"
M81    "Fragment of monoterpenes"
M87    "Methylbutenols"
M137   "Monoterpenes"
"""

# Create dataframe containing substance codes and names
df_subs = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(subs_strings), header=None,
                      names=['subs', 'subs_name'], index_col=False,
                      delim_whitespace=True)

# Add units and variable names matching the substance codes
# Do this for gas concentrations
for var in var_conc:
    var_subs, var_unit_raw = var.split('(')
    var_subs_num = var_subs.lstrip('M ')
    var_unit = var_unit_raw.rstrip(')')
    for i, subs in enumerate(df_subs['subs']):
        if var_subs_num == subs.lstrip('M'):
            df_subs.loc[i, 'conc_unit'] = var_unit
            df_subs.loc[i, 'conc_var'] = var
# Do this for gas fluxes
for var in var_flux:
    var_subs_num = var.split('M')[1].lstrip()
    var_unit = rng.choice(['unit_a', 'unit_b', 'unit_c'])
    for i, subs in enumerate(df_subs['subs']):
        if var_subs_num == subs.lstrip('M'):
            df_subs.loc[i, 'flux_unit'] = var_unit
            df_subs.loc[i, 'flux_var'] = var
```

```
df_subs

#     subs  subs_name                              conc_unit conc_var     flux_unit flux_var   
# 0   M33   Methanol                               ppbv      M 33(ppbv)   unit_c    Flux_M 33  
# 1   M39   Water cluster                          ncps      M 39(ncps)   NaN       NaN        
# 2   M45   Acetaldehyde                           ppbv      M 45(ppbv)   unit_a    Flux_M 45  
# 3   M47   Unknown                                ppbv      M 47(ppbv)   unit_b    Flux_M 47  
# 4   M59   Acetone                                ppbv      M 59(ppbv)   unit_a    Flux_M 59  
# 5   M61   Unknown                                ppbv      M 61(ppbv)   unit_c    Flux_M 61  
# 6   M69   Isoprene                               ppbv      M 69(ppbv)   unit_a    Flux_M 69  
# 7   M71   Methyl vinyl, ketone and methacrolein  ppbv      M 71(ppbv)   unit_a    Flux_M 71  
# 8   M81   Fragment of monoterpenes               ppbv      M 81(ppbv)   unit_c    Flux_M 81  
# 9   M87   Methylbutenols                         ppbv      M 87(ppbv)   unit_c    Flux_M 87  
# 10  M137  Monoterpenes                           ppbv      M 137(ppbv)  unit_b    Flux_M 137
```

#### Create plotting function based on pandas

Here is one way of creating a plotting function that lets you select the variables for the plot with the `graph_type` argument. It works by selecting the relevant variables from the substances table using the `if/elif` statement. This and the `ec_top[variables].plot(...)` function are all that is really necessary to create the plot, the rest is all for formatting the figure. The variables are plotted in the order of the `variables` list. I draw only two columns of subplots because of width constraints here (max 10 inches width to get a sharp image on Stack Overflow).

```
# Create plotting function that creates a single figure showing all
# variables of the chosen type

def plot_grid(graph_type):
    
    # Set the type of variables and units to fetch in df_subs: using if
    # statements for the strings lets you use a variety of strings
    if 'conc' in graph_type:
        var_type = 'conc_var'
        unit_type = 'conc_unit'
    elif 'flux' in graph_type:
        var_type = 'flux_var'
        unit_type = 'flux_unit'
    else:
        return f'Error: "{graph_type}" is not a valid string, \
it must contain "conc" or "flux".'

    # Create list of variables to plot depending on type
    variables = df_subs[var_type].dropna()
    
    # Set parameters for figure dimensions
    nvar = variables.size
    cols = 2
    rows = int(np.ceil(nvar/cols))
    width = 10/cols
    height = 3

    # Draw grid of line plots: note that x_compat is used to override the
    # default x-axis time labels, remove it if you do not want to use custom
    # tick locators and formatters like the ones created in the loop below
    grid = ec_top[variables].plot(subplots=True, figsize=(cols*width, rows*height),
                                  layout=(rows, cols), marker='.', linestyle='',
                                  xlabel='Time', x_compat=True)

    # The code in the following loop is optional formatting based on my
    # preferences, if you remove it the plot should still look ok but with
    # fewer informative labels and the legends may not all be in the same place

    # Loop through the subplots to edit format, including creating labels and
    # titles based on the information in the substances table (df_subs):
    for ax in grid.flatten()[:nvar]:
        # Edit tick locations and format
        plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(which='both'), fontsize=8, rotation=0, ha='center')
        loc = mdates.AutoDateLocator()
        ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(loc)
        ax.set_xticks([], minor=True)
        fmt = mdates.ConciseDateFormatter(loc, show_offset=False)
        ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(fmt)
        # Edit legend
        handle, (var_name,) = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
        subs = df_subs[df_subs[var_type] == var_name]['subs']
        ax.legend(handle, subs, loc='upper right')
        # Add y label
        var_unit, = df_subs[df_subs[var_type] == var_name][unit_type]
        ylabel_type = f'{"Concentration" if "conc" in graph_type else "Flux"}'
        ax.set_ylabel(f'{ylabel_type} [{var_unit}]')
        # Add title
        subs_name, = df_subs[df_subs[var_type] == var_name]['subs_name']
        ax.set_title(subs_name)


    # Edit figure format
    fig = plt.gcf()
    date = df_conc.index[0].strftime('%b %d %Y')
    title_type = f'{"concentrations" if "conc" in graph_type else "fluxes"}'
    fig.suptitle(f'BVOCs {title_type} on {date} from 12:00 to 13:00',
                 y=0.93, fontsize=15);
    fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.3, hspace=0.4)

    plt.show()
```

```
plot_grid('conc') # any kind of string works if it contains 'conc' or 'flux'
```

[image: plot_grid_conc]

```
plot_grid('graph fluxes')
```

[image: plot_grid_flux]

---

Documentation: [matplotlib date ticks](https://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html)